# How to prevent FxCop from analyzing auto-generated code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, code-analysis, fxcop

FxCop (tool for static code analysis) gives me an error while checking code behind of .edmx model. How to prevent FxCop from analyzing auto-generated code (or at least Entity Framework generated classes)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have moved to Visual Studio Code Analysis, as it gives me the same functionality as FxCop.

From [FxCop blog](http://davesbox.com/archive/2008/08/17/fxcop-1-36-released.aspx):

> "That's correct, they are different products (FxCop and VS Code Analysys), however they do have a common engine. Visual Studio 2008 SP1 already comes with the same fixes and analysis (plus a little bit more), so there is no need to 'update' Visual Studio with the latest FxCop."

But nevertheless *Suppress results from generated code* option (project properties -> code analysis tab) for some reason does not preventing from code analysis for auto generated code of .edmx model.

Then I've found [blog](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2010/02/09/customizing-the-entity-framework-t4-template-suppressing-code-analysis.aspx), which helped me solve this issue.

Comment: First link in answer is dead - *"404 Not Found"*.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the `/ignoregeneratedcode` switch in the project that contained the auto-generated code that I did not want FxCop to analyze.

Here is an MSDN FAQ about [how to prevent FxCop 1.36 from firing warnings against auto generated code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/codeanalysis/faq-how-do-i-prevent-fxcop-1-36-from-firing-warnings-against-generated-code).

Answer (score 0):

You can skip assembly or rules(use checkbox in FxCop.exe to skip rules or assembly. Or even create your new rules for FxCop to suit your standard.  FxCop also provide attributes which classes you do not want to verify.